# A simple Oracle UPDATE query in SQL developer is taking too much of time, why?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Can someone please tell me the reason why a simple UPDATE query in SQL developer is taking so much of time and eventually says TIMEOUT without update.

It works for other rows in the same table but a particular row is not getting updated. Why?

Not working Query:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET AVAILABLE='Y' WHERE DEPT_ID='055FGH1FGH5HG5';
```

Working Query:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET AVAILABLE='Y' WHERE DEPT_ID='455FGH1FGH5521';
```

It is getting stuck for only particular DEPT_ID i.e., `'055FGH1FGH5HG5'`, why?

Comment: Might be that row is locked by other user

Comment: @Tejash Or, as is very often the case when people experience locks while developing: it's not another user, but it's you, in another window/session.  :) Make sure to commit/rollback or just end all your sessions by closing clients and retry.

Comment: Maybe you have 10,000,000 rows where N_EFT_ID = '455FGH1FGH5521'. Or maybe you have 100 rows, AND that column is included in 25 indexes. Or...there are lots of scenarios that could come into play. Take a look at your session wait events and the execution plan for that update. If it's still running, if you have it licensed, give the Real Time SQL Monitoring report a look-see.

Comment: But I have only 1 row with DEPT_ID='055FGH1FGH5HG5' in my DB

Comment: Read the rest of my advice - and we can't know what data you have, you haven't shown us.